# Beginner Probability Question: Find PDF and E(X)

Tags: expected-value, density-function

From [1;2] continuous interval we choose 3 numbers randomly. Let $X$ be the minimum between those numbers.

Find PDF and Expected value.

I fail to understand the problem, since I believe that probability of a precise number to be chosen out of continuous interval is 0. I saw somewhere that it could be solved by CDF $= (2-x)^3$, but I don't know how we get it.

I'd be glad, if you could provide some explanation for a beginner.

Comment: are the numbers drawn independently from each other?

Comment: Start by finding the probability all three numbers are greater than some given $x$, i.e. that $\min(X_1,X_2,X_3)>x$; this will be affected by whether $x<1$ or $1<x<2$ or $2<x$. Then find the CDF for the minimum, then the PDF, then the expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> probability of a precise number to be chosen out of continuous interval is 0

You're right, but what you says is probability *mass* function (PMF), and what the question says is probability *density* function (PDF).

For example, $\Pr(X = 1.5) = 0$ but $\Pr(1.5 < X \leq 1.6) > 0$ and $\Pr(1.5 < X \leq 1.5 + \Delta x) > 0$. Moreover, $\Pr(1.5 < X \leq 1.5 + \Delta x)$ is roughly proportional to $\Delta x$ and $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \Pr(1.5 < X \leq 1.5 + \Delta x) / \Delta x$ (probability mass / range) is called probability density.

---

We'll derive by CDF, because definition of CDF contains a “$\leq$”, which is suitable for describing the minimum.

CDF of each number is

$$
F(x)
:= \Pr(X \leq x)
= \begin{cases}
0 & x < 1. \\
x-1 & 1 \leq x < 2. \\
1 & 2 \leq x.
\end{cases}
$$

Now can you follow Henry's comment?

(It's not necessary to fully understand PDF for calculating CDF)

Comment: Thanks, very informative explanation!